# Printf don't show the variable, but a random number

Tags: c

I am starting to learn C. Today I was trying a little program that just do a average point starting from 3 input.

After all I wanted to print the number of the averages done in the session, so I insert a simple

```
counter=counter+1;
```

into the main while loop and a

```
printf("you done the average %d times", counter);
```

before the return 0.
The problem is: if I do the average for just 1 or 2 times, the counter show 
every time a different number, never the right, but ever around the int maximum. I tried everything, but it don't work. Where is my mistakes?

This is my first post on this site, i read the rules but i'm sorry if i'm breaking just one. The variable "counter" is declared.

```
int main()
{
int vote1, vote2, vote3, tot, media, contatore, err;
char opz;

do{
```

after this, i start an while loop, and this is its end:

```
contatore=contatore+1;          

}   while(opz!='n');
printf("hai eseguito la media %d volte", contatore);

return 0;
```

obviously the code is in italian, where counter=contatore

Comment: Yes, we need to see the declaration of `counter` and all assignments to it. Don't post more than a kB of code.

Comment: Please show ALL the relevant code.

Comment: 1. Use a debugger to see what your program is doing. 2. Post the complete code which we can copy and paste to compile and run.

Comment: Just in case you didn't. `int counter = 0;` instead of `int counter;`

Comment: Ok, thanks very mych evan, i was going crazy. My book don't speak about this, at least till the control structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to initialise the variable:

```
int contatore = 0;
```

Comment: +1 Strictly speaking, the initializer is not mandatory. It's plausible to define the variable first and assign a value afterwards `int contatore; /* ... code that does not use contatore value ... */ contatore = 0;`